# Looping Over a Group of Steps in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch job with the following workflow:

**Start**

**Step**: Fetch the list of IDs to export via an SQL query.

While there are data in the list, perform the following steps:

1. **Step**: Fetch data for the next ID via an SQL query
2. **Step**: Compress the fetched data

**End**

I tried to create a flow containing my two tasks to loop over.

```
    public Flow myFlow(){
        FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow> flowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>("processFlow");
        flowBuilder.start(getDataStep());
        flowBuilder.next(compressDataStep());
        flowBuilder.end();
        return flowBuilder.build();
    }
```

Then use a FlowJob to integrate into the Flow, but it doesn't work :

```
public FlowJobBuilder jobBuilder() {
    JobBuilder jobBuilder = new JobBuilder(getJobDescription().getJobName(), jobRepository);
    FlowJobBuilder sjb = new FlowJobBuilder(jobBuilder);
    MyDecider decider = new MyDecider();

    sjb.start(startStep())
            .next(myFlow())
            .next(decider).on("COMPLETED").to(endStep())
            .from(decider).on("REPEAT").to(myFlow())
            .end()
            .build();
    return sjb;
}
```

Do you have a way to loop over a group of Steps in Spring Batch until a condition is met?